# Date formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime, date

Using the following:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

I get:

```
Mon Feb 22 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

How do I format this too

```
22-02-1993
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [`getFullYear`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.10), [`getMonth`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.12) (note that the values start with `0`), and [`getDate`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.14) functions on the `Date` instance, then assemble a string. (Those links are to the specification, which can be hard to read; [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does a bit better.)

Or use a library like [DateJS](http://datejs.com) (although it hasn't been maintained in quite some time) or as [joidegn mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9602956/157247), [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: @joidegn: Yeah, and it's not because it's bug-free. :-) I was just looking with great interest at your link.

Comment: a pitty because I quite like datejs syntax.

Answer (score 2):

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) works nicely. NAtive Javascript unfortunately lacks somewhat in this regard although You could cocatenate the date elements together.

Answer (score 0):

```
var month = date.getMonth();
date.getDate() + "-" + (month >= 10 ? month : '0' + month) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
```

Read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) about Date object in Javascript

Comment: With his example date that will give him `22-1-1993`. And w3schools is not a good reference, strongly recommend [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) or the specification.